# Revokable Discretionary Tree

Tags: data-structures, hierarchy, graph-theory, hierarchical-data, access-control

For my own understanding, I'm writing a Hierarchical Discretionary Access System. It is not DAC, it is more akin to Discretionary RBAC, but those details do not matter for the question at hand.

Each `user` has a certain `Role`; each `Role` has a certain set of `permissions`.
Each `Role` is organised in a hierarchical tree-like structure: the `role` named *root* has all permissions; child roles of *root* have a subset of the permission of their parent role.

Schematic views of the above: [image: schematic view]

Let's say that a `user` with the `role` named *manager* decides to delegate the `permission` named *set_salary* to a `user` with the `role` named *programmer*, who subsequently delegates this `permission` to the `user` with the `role` named *intern*.

Somebody decides to fire said `user` with the role named *manager*. As a result, the `role` named *manager* is revoked from said `user`. What is more, *all permissions delegated by said `user` also need to be revoked*.

**So my question is:**
Is there a data structure which facilitates easy identification of:

- the chain of permissions delegated by a certain subject within a hierarchical tree structure;
- whether or not a certain permission has been delegated to a certain subject?

Comment: Have you looked into ABAC?

Comment: @DavidBrossard, yeah, I'm aware of ABAC; it is quite fashionable atm. It is however solving a different problem while lacking in auditability. There are, of course, many options for hybrid models. Anyhow, in this case I'm writing my own to deepen my understanding of access systems.

Comment: @Jacco It seems that I have completely misunderstood the problem, and my answer makes no sense with respect to the context at all.  Am I right?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi, I'm not sure yet. An adjacency list may be the correct data structure to use, although I'm not sure it will provide easy access to the delegation chain. I'm still working on it and will comment on your answer when I know more.

Comment: @Jacco Oh Okay! All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an **[adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)** ?
Or in other words, 'a list of linked lists', similar to how we use it in representing graphs.

Each user can be associated with a delegation linked list.
A node of the delegation linked list can be of the form `<permissionId, userId>`, denoting that the owner of the linked list has delegated the permission `permissionId` to the user `userId`. Then we can go through the linked list of the user `userId` and repeat the same process recursively until we find a user whose delegation linked list is empty.

This algorithm is basically the same as [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: I used an adjacency list. I'm still not sure it is the best solution, but, in a relational database, it *does* supports cascading constraints; a feature missing when from the [nested sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) solution (which is more *efficient* at querying a subtree), while I don't like the denormalization required by a [closure table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree).

Comment: That's great Jacco! I'm glad that the answer could be of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

This model can't support delegation of permission per a user like you described for manager -> programmer -> intern situation. Permissions are set for a role and setting new permission for a role effects all users that has that role.

To support permission delegation per a user, new relation is needed that describes delegation. Data needed to describe it is: which user gave permission, which user received permission and permission that is delegated. Like, relation delegatedPermission with columns:

- giveUserId
- receiveUserId
- permissionId

Comment: I'm aware that the current model cannot support delegation; it needs an extra data structure to keep track of the delegation chain. I asked this question to help me find a suitable data structure for the delegation chain which support the requirements as outlined in the OP.